# WSGIScriptAlias overrides Alias

Tags: python, wsgi

I'm having an issue configuring mod_wsgi with Apache 2.2. I need mod_wsgi to handle everything under root directory of a virtual server except certain paths. For those paths I want ordinary Apache directory listing to work. The following virtual server config half works. mod_wsgi does not kick in for paths directly to files but does for directories. I can't figure this out. Looked at docs here - https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide. It shows using aliases in the way I have to disable mod_wsgi but does not mention this problem. (Note not that it matters but the `foo.wsgi` end point is just the hello world example).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain
    ServerName test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain

    <Directory /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
        AllowOverride FileInfo Options Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

  Alias /static /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain/static

  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain/cgi-bin/foo.wsgi

  <Directory /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain/cgi-bin>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried disabling any handler with the following but it does not work:

```
<Location "/static">
  SetHandler None
</Location>

<LocationMatch ^/static>
  SetHandler None
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting and end slash after static?

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain/static/

<Directory /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain/static/>
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/test.wsgi.sethandler.localdomain/cgi-bin/foo.wsgi
```

Comment: Yes I tried that. It's not supposed to be any different, except that 1. You should either have trailing slash on alias and target or omit it from both and 2. using a trailing slash on alias wont match say "/static" only "/static/" - with a trailing slash. Ref https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias. Also the `Require all granted` did not do anything to help.